# Can i force android to use my app as intent receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

So my app is hardly rely on WebView. Its almost like a browser for a specific website, but i parse all HTML and etc. WebView contains links to a different parts of website. I want user to use my app to display them( because mobile version of site is ugly and very bad, that's why i created a client which display everything nice) but google chrome also can can do it and suggest to open those links in browser.  For sure user can just open links with my app and tap "remember my choice", but that's looks not that great. I want android to open those links only with my app at least when it happens in my app. I use intent filter to suggest my app

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
          <data
              android:host="mysite.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/prefix/"
              android:scheme="https" />
       <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix -->
</intent-filter>
```

Can i somehow force android to open it with my app? Or tell user to choose my app and ask him to "remember my choice" at the app opening? Because its not typically app behavior and user can be confused that he can open different things in website client with google chrome.

Comment: So you need to open your app directly without asking any choice to user?

Comment: No, i want to use user to choose my app as intent reciever. For example, he clicked on something in my client, android suggest 2 apps that can handle it, mine and browser(google chrome for example), i want user to choose my app. I can manually tell him to use my app at the opening, or user can just choose my app and remember his choice. But i wondered can i just always use my app as intent reciver. I can add code from my activity which responsible for intent reciving.

Answer (score 0):

As u said
**For example, he clicked on something in my client**
I think you can add packageName in the Intent with the action_view. such as

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("******");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
intent.setPackage("ur app's pkgname");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The problem is that fact, that links contains in WebView, i dont create intents manually in code

Comment: @EvgenyYurin If the app user click isn't ur app, I don't think u can direct use use ur app to receive this action.